# Firebase schedule a function with multiple crontabs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I want my function to run once a day, but twice on weekends. How do I do that with Firebase?

My crontabs:

- 0 16 * * *
- 0 22 * * 6,0

From what I know, my only chooce is to create another instance of the same function with a different crontab. Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I know, my only choice is to create another instance of the
> same function with a different crontab. Is there a better way?

Yes, this is the only solution. However you can put the "main" code in one function, as follows:

```
exports.scheduledFunction1 = functions.pubsub.schedule('...').onRun(async (context) => {

    try {
        await mainFunction();
        return null;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }

});


exports.scheduledFunction2 = functions.pubsub.schedule('...').onRun(async (context) => {
    try {
        await mainFunction();
        return null;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
});

async function mainFunction() {

    //await ...
    
}
```